# Fixing newline problem inside string that is passed to api

Tags: javascript, html

```
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;    
body: `{
    "prompt": "${input}",
    "max_tokens": ${range}
    }`
```

I pass the input variable to the api with this code. My input var is a textarea element. It works if i enter a regular text with no newlines (pressing enter/return button). But if i give something like:

```
Hi my name
is something
```

It returns an error.

Comment: I think you are looking for `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what error you got?

Comment: Why are you making this a string in the first place?

Comment: @Evert  Should i JSON.stringify(input) and then pass the stringified variable to the "prompt" ?

Comment: it looks to me the content of `body` is JSON. So no, use it for the entire object you're trying to serialize.

Comment: @nico It looks like just a 400 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON, newlines have to be converted to the escape sequence `\n`. Your code will put literal newlines in in the `body` string.

Rather than constructing the JSON body as a string, create an object and use `JSON.stringify`

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    prompt: inpput,
    max_tokens: range
})
```

You should *never* try to construct JSON by hand. Every language you're likely to use has built-in or library functions to create and parse JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's working now! I have one question, there is another property of body called "stop" and i was using it as "stop": ["AI:","Human:"]. The api doc says i should send string or array so i was using it this way, without the JSON.stringify. But now it doesn't work with this property. Its working when i remove this "stop" property  but if i add it as stop: ["AI:", "Human:"] , it doesn't work. Am i doing something wrong? other properties are working with the same syntax

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you put `stop` in quotes in JavaScript. Either way, JSON.stringify should convert it properly.

Comment: Did you remember to add a comma at the end of the previous line of the object?